# Is it possible to create a dynamic web 3.0 using struts-el 1.2.9 for websphere 8.5 deployment

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, struts-1, ibm-rad

As the question implies.
Would there be any conflict when using dynamic web 3.0 project in RAD/eclipse with the library struts 1.2.9 to be deployed in websphere 8.5.1
Reason is that i'm migrating from websphere 5.1 using struts 1.1, but was wondering if i would encounter any difficulties if i do this migration.

Cheers.

I got the following error:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No form found under
>   'SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean' in locale 'en_US'     at
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.html.JavascriptValidatorTag.renderJavascript(JavascriptValidatorTag.java:384)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.html.JavascriptValidatorTag.doStartTag(JavascriptValidatorTag.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.strutsel.taglib.html.ELJavascriptValidatorTag.doStartTag(ELJavascriptValidatorTag.java:218)
>     at
>   com.ibm._jsp._SA_5F_SecretQuestions._jspx_meth_html$1el_javascript_0(_SA_5F_SecretQuestions.java:304)
>     at
>   com.ibm._jsp._SA_5F_SecretQuestions._jspService(_SA_5F_SecretQuestions.java:140)
>     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>     at com.web.sa.SecurityServlet.doFilter(SecurityServlet.java:75)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at com.web.sa.SAReqLoggerServlet.doFilter(SAReqLoggerServlet.java:62)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:716)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:412)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1066)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)

but the form is in the source:
web\src\com\web\sa\SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean.java

my web config:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
...
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config/jsp/sa</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config-sa.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
...
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
</web-app>
```

my sturts configs are:
struts-config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
                               "struts-config_1_2.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <!-- Data Sources -->
    <data-sources></data-sources>

    <!-- Form Beans -->
    <form-beans>
...
        <form-bean name="SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean" type="com.web.sa.SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean"></form-bean>
...
</form-beans>
...
</struts-config>
```

struts-config-sa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
                               "struts-config_1_2.dtd">

<struts-config>
...
    <form-beans>
...
    <form-bean name="SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean" type="com.web.sa.SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean"></form-bean>
...
    </form-beans>
...
    <action-mappings>
...
    <action path="/SAChangeSecretQAs" 
            name="SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean" 
            type="com.web.sa.SAChangeSecretQAsAction" scope="session" input="success">
        <forward name="success" path="jsp/sa/SA_SecretQuestions.jsp"></forward>
        <forward name="logout" path="jsp/sa/SALogout.do?buttonPressed=logout&amp;CASE_FORWARD=YES"></forward>
        <forward name="access" path="jsp/sa/SAAccessDetails.do?CASE_FORWARD=YES"></forward>
    </action>
...
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean.java

```
package com.web.common;

public class SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean extends ValidatorForm
{
...
}
```

SAChangeSecretQAsAction.java

```
package com.web.sa;
public class SAChangeSecretQAsAction extends Action
{
    public ActionForward executeAction(
                    ActionMapping mapping,
                    ActionForm form,
                    HttpServletRequest req,
                    HttpServletResponse res)
                    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
...
    }
...
}
```

SA_SecretQuestions.jsp

```
<%@ include file = "../common/header.inc"%>
<%
  try {
      %>
<html-el:javascript formName="SAChangeSecretQAsFormBean" staticJavascript="false" dynamicJavascript="true" page="0" />
      <%
  }
  catch (Exception x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
  }
%>
```

header.inc

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ taglib uri="../../WEB-INF/struts-html-el.tld" prefix="html-el" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="../../WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="../../WEB-INF/struts-logic-el.tld" prefix="logic-el" %>
<%@ page import ="com.constant.*" buffer="16kb" errorPage="../errorpages/GenericErrorPage.jsp"  %>

<%String cacheReq=null;%>

<html-el:base/>
<html> 
<HEAD>
```

if any other information are missing please do tell..
thanks

Comment: What kind of conflict? Most of your issues will be the migration from 1.1 => 1.2.9.

Comment: Hi Dave, I edited the question..
Thanks for the concern